# How to Reduce Current in Solenoid Coil

Tags: frequency, solenoid, current-limiting, solenoid-valve, inrush-current

First time poster and electrical newbie here. First off I just want to thank everyone for helping create such a great and helpful forum!  I've been lurking for years and have learned a lot here!

I have a solenoid valve that is only available in 120VAC/60Hz and for a number of reasons I have to use this exact component in a 220VAC/50Hz application.  I have already spec'ed out a transformer to drop the voltage down from 220VAC to 120VAC.

After reading this post: [50Hz vs 60Hz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139118/60hz-to-50hz-frequency-transformer-inverter), I learned that running at 50Hz compared to 60Hz will cause in increase in current - which I'm worried will damage the solenoid coil or lead to premature failure.  I ran through the calculation and spec'ed out a power resistor to put in series with the coil to reduce the current, however this also causes a 20V drop. So with the power resistor, the solenoid will only see 100VAC instead of 120VAC. So now, I'm worried that the lower voltage may prevent the solenoid from actuating properly especially during inrush.  The nominal steady-state current of the coil is 0.5A but peak inrush is 6.5A.

My question is this, is there any component or approach that I can use to limit current during steady-state only without dropping voltage?  Ideally, I would have 120VAC, 0.5A (steady-state) going through the coil while still allowing the peak inrush into the coil of 6.5A.  Outside of investing in a very expensive frequency convertor, is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?  Maybe it's impossible, but you never know unless you try!

Thanks for all the help!

Edit 1: To answer Joren's question below, the spec sheet and the manufacturer say that this solenoid is designed only for 60Hz.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the datasheet of the component to verify that the frequency difference is an issue - it could be that you are still within spec of the component.

Comment: This isn't a forum so your lurking may have been ineffective!

Comment: I reckon that if you spoke nicely to the manufacturer of the solenoid valve they might be able to fit a suitable coil for you, thus eliminating the need for a transformer (saving cost, assembly time, weight...).